# How may I convert the datetime sql to c# by using linq?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Below is my sql code:
`SELECT * FROM test.operator_error_transaction WHERE operator_token = 12345 && transaction_date_time BETWEEN '2019-05-22';`

I have tried my c# code below and got some error in comparing the datetime:

```
var id = (from firstn in _context.OperatorErrorTransaction
                  where firstn.OperatorToken == "12345"
                  where firstn.TransactionDateTime >= '2019-05-22'
                  select firstn).ToList();
        return Ok(id);
```

Comment: what is your datatype of `TransactionDateTime` column. Also post your error.

Comment: TransactionDateTime datatype is datetime

Comment: Then use `DateTime` in C#, not `string` (or `char` - which won't even compile in your example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use DateTime type for conversion.

```
 var mydate = Convert.ToDateTime("2019-05-22");
 var id = (from firstn in _context.OperatorErrorTransaction
                  where firstn.OperatorToken == "12345"
                  where firstn.TransactionDateTime >= mydate 
                  select firstn).ToList();
        return Ok(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert your string to datetime. This will work.

```
Convert.ToDateTime("2019-05-22")
```

Comment: If values are getting from different database, most of the times all database prefer to stored date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. So we can convert easily to `DateTime`

Comment: No major database stores datetime in **any** string format. They store them as numbers. The key principle with dates (in C#, or databases, or whatever) is this - avoid storing them as strings **as much as possible**.

Comment: if `datetime` is in other format in database there is other format to convert to `datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
var startInclusive= new DateTime(2019,5,22); // if you really must, use `DateTime.TryParseExact` here
var endExclusive = startInclusive.AddDays(1);

var id = (from firstn in _context.OperatorErrorTransaction
            where firstn.OperatorToken == "12345"
                  && firstn.TransactionDateTime >= startInclusive
                  && firstn.TransactionDateTime < endExclusive
            select firstn).ToList();
return Ok(id);
```

This avoids any issues relating to culture and date formats. And it gets all data where the transaction occurred someone on 22 May 2019 (whatever the time component) and has [good performance characteristics](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea).

Answer (score -3):

sql date format is YYYY-MM-DD and c# date format is DD-MM-YYYY.

Please change either of the date formats.

Comment: C# doesn't have a date format. Cultures have date formats. C# can convert a `DateTime` to a string for a given culture, but the `DateTime` object is (internally) only a `long` value and has no inherent string representation.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't necessarily have YMD as a date format either. It could be YDM, for example.